# TFSBuild Powershell step turning script arguments into strings. How to avoid this?

Tags: powershell, tfs, arguments, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've configured the following arguments in a Powershell build step: `-protocol:http -portsToOpen 9512,9513,9512`.

Once TFSBuild runs the whole script, it throws the following error:

> "System.Int32[]". Error: "Cannot convert
>   "9512,9513,9515" to "System.Int32"

The problem is TFSBuild is running the script sorrounding 9512,9513,9515 with quots (i.e. `'9512,9513,9515'`).

Is there any solution for this? One possible workaround would be running `powershell.exe` from a Command build step... But I'd like to know if there's some direct solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use TFS but I can tell you PowerShell is parsing that as an integer array (`System.Int32[]`) and trying to pass that as an argument to `-portsToOpen`

If you don't have variables on that line you could use the [stop parsing operator --%](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) as that

> directs Windows PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as Windows PowerShell commands or expressions.
>
> `icacls X:\VMS --% /grant Dom\HVAdmin:(CI)(OI)F`

You could also *actually* put it in quotes so that PowerShell just treats it as a string. I could not find the documentation to back up how it expects input for that parameter so I am not sure.

Comment: Uhm it's true I could use the `--%` operator. I'll give a try this next monday, because it's a project at work and I don't have access from internet to company's TFS